# Numpy: create an array of arrays using vstack

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to create a numpy arrays of arrays using vstack, but I got this error message: `all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly`

What I tried so far:

```
all_exp = np.array([])

for idx, rw in df_gamma_count.iterrows():
    exp = rw['Pr_A_perc'] * ( rw['gamma_index'] * float(row['spread_perc']) * (1+f) - (f+f) )
    gamma_and_exp = [exp, rw['gamma_index']]
    all_exp = np.vstack((all_exp,gamma_and_exp))
```

Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: what are the shapes of arrays `all_exp` and `gamma_and_exp`?

Comment: `all_exp` starts out with shape (0,).  DId you check that?  What's the shape of `gamma_and_exp`?  Is it too (0,) or maybe (1,0)?  Otherwise the `vstack` won't work.  You didn't try this `vstack` step by step in an interactive session, did you?

Comment: Doing `vstack` like this repeatedly is wrong.  You have to understand shapes to get the initial array right.  And it is slow, making a new array at each step.  It's better to collect all arrays in a list, and do one `vstack` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [`numpy.vstack()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) to work, the number of columns should match in all the 2D arrays. For example:

```
In [14]: arr1 = np.arange(2*4).reshape(2, 4)
In [15]: arr2 = np.arange(5*4).reshape(5, 4) 

In [16]: np.vstack((arr1, arr2)) 
Out[16]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

The error message

> all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

means that, in this example, we are stacking along axis 0. So, all the dimensions apart from axis 0 should match.

For example, in the shapes

```
(2, 4)
(5, 4)
 ^  ^
 |  |
 |  dimension of this axis should match.
 dimensions along this axis can be different since we'are concatenating along axis 0.
```